# Python Referencing

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to read data from a text field. The name of the text field is not defined of found in the other class with methods of reading the text field. The textfield is defined in the Design class. now how do I access this field from another class, so I can read data from it. Thanks!!

**Edit:**

I have 2 Classes: FeatureImportCommonWidget(QtGui.QWidget) and MetaDataBrowser. FeatureImportCommonWidget contains a Text Field called placesGroupBox. I want to access this text field in the MetaDataBrowser Class.

I tried it using "filename = get_metadata.placesGroupBox.text()", but it gives an error about placesGroupBox not being defined in the MetaDataBrowser class.

Comment: Hi, please state which libraries you are using.

Comment: 1.  Please provide some sample of what you're doing.  2.  Please provide code you you attempted to solve this.  Include the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

If the field's an ordinary attribute called `text` and your `Design` instance is called `design`, you can access (read/write) it from anywhere as `design.text`.

Comment: I have 2 Classes. The FeatureImportCommonWidget(QtGui.QWidget) and the MetaDataBrowser. on the "FeatureImportCommonWidget(QtGui.QWidget)" Class, I have a Text Field called, placesGroupBox in this Class. now I want to access this text field in the MetaDataBrowser Class. How do i go about doing that. I tried it using " filename = get_metadata.placesGroupBox.text()", and It gives an error abt placesGroupBox not being defined in the MetaDataBrowser Class, Please Assist!!

Comment: When an object called `widget` has an attribute called `box`, you can access that attribute anywhere in your code as `widget.box`.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  if object of *FeatureImportCommonWidget* class is created inside of *MetaDataBrowser* class, you can access your text field anywhere inside *MetaDataBrowser* class like this: `FeatureImportCommonWidgetObjectName.placesGroupBox.text()`

**2**   if object of *FeatureImportCommonWidget* class is created before *MetaDataBrowser* class, you can pass that object as parameter to *MetaDataBrowser* class and then access your text field anywhere inside *MetaDataBrowser* class like in step **1**